# Plans for Sharepoint to support MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, asp.net-mvc-2

Has Microsoft said anything in the past year about Sharepoint supporting MVC (in a nice, non-hacky way)?

I know Scott Gu said something on the subject, but that was just shy of 3 years ago (Feb 2008).

Are they still "looking at it" for the future? (3 years seems a long time to be "looking")

Did they decide against it? (the whole MVC thing is just a fad, it will die out...?)

Or have they been mute on the subject?

(We are about to embark on an enterprise level implementation of Sharepoint and I am worried that we are investing a lot of time and money into an old way of doing things.)

Note: I know that there are questions like this out there, but they seem to be about a year old, so I thought I would ask again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't hold your breath for SharePoint to go MVC. SharePoint contains a lot of custom controls that would have to be rewritten completely, if they changed the underlying model. Changing from ASP.NET Web Forms to ASP.NET MVC would probably result in a whole different branch of SharePoint - think SharePoint MVC. And if Microsoft was to go that way, they would probably choose a different path for that solution, perhaps even backing the open source CMS Umbraco.

I personally believe that MVC is not a fad. It you care about what your html ends up looking like, then ASP.NET MVC is a great platform. And with the popularity of HTML 5 rising, I see the same thing happening for ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

It's a huge breaking change, so I'm ruling it out for SharePoint 2010, also because newer MVC Versions are .net 4.0 only and SharePoint 2010 is .net 3.5 and will highly unlikely go to 4.0, again because it's a huge breaking change.

I saw some hackish attempts, but getting even Routing to work with the Virtual Path Provider of Sharepoint...

I'd say: Wait for SharePoint 2014 or whatver the next Version will be.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry too much about it. Treat it as a platform that you plug in to, so the way it works doesn't have a huge impact on your implementation apart from around web parts. If it goes MVC then everyone will have the same pain of moving their web parts from the current model to an MVC type rendering one so MS will have to provide some help in making the transition.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/29/mvc-or-web-forms-a-dying-question.aspx) is about a year old but I thought the author's perspective on the choice between SharePoint (a platform) and ASP.NET MVC (a framework) was refreshing at the time.  I've had experience with both and I've gotta say that I'd be hesitant to mix the two technologies right now.

The only thing I think is safe to say right now is that SharePoint is here to stay and ASP.NET MVC is gaining tremendous popularity / support and is unlikely to go away.

EDIT: There are also a number of comments in that link that might relate to your question.